# What happens if I compile my code with AVX instructions, but then run the code on a CPU without AVX extensions?

Tags: gcc, x86, avx

If I use the `-mavx` flag with GCC (to use AVX instructions), but then run on a CPU that doesn't support AVX, what is the behavior? Does the program crash, produce undefined behavior, or something else?

Comment: Unsupported AVX instructions will generate and #UD (undefined) exception, crashing your program (if you don't handle the exception).

Comment: It will crash, unless your code does not actually produce AVX code (e.g., if you don't do any floating point math and no vectorized integer math).

Comment: @chtz: Another case when GCC will use `movdqa` or `movaps` (or `vmovdqa` with `-mavx`) is inline expansion of small or medium memset or memcpy, or copying a struct, or initializing an array or struct.  This can easily happen even with `-O2` (no autovectorization) in pure integer code.

Comment: If you compile in a way that actually makes AVX instructions execute, duplicate of [Illegal instruction from VS C++ on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59584105).  But it sounds like you're really asking what if you compile with `-mavx`, in which case it's not *guaranteed* to use any SIMD at all.